# Is it possible to save a file such as .swf, .mp3, .txt, etc. without the "save as" prompt using javascript in a specific directory?

Tags: javascript, flash, node-webkit, swfupload, nw.js

I am developing a node-webkit application. I would like to download a .swf file when I clicked a button and automatically save it to a specific directory.
Right now, I can download it but a "save as" dialog is prompting. Is it possible to disable it and just automatically save it?
Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: `when I clicked a button and automatically save it to a specific directory` I can't say about Javascript but you can use PHP for such a feature. Try these **[google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=save+file+to+downloads+folder+using+php)** for a hint if you have PHP

Comment: Okay. Let me check this feature. Thank you. I will let you know what will be the result. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Otherwise malicious websites would be able to overwrite important files on your computer

Comment: I see. Does Node JS can do such feature?

Comment: AFAIK Node is a JavaScript runtime for writing backend code. Typically it'll serve up webpages for your browser, but otherwise have no access to the client machine

Comment: Okay then. Thank you. I have found a possible solution for this using this:
http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html

I dont have any conclusion for this. I will let everyone know. :)
Thank you so much for the information you gave.

Comment: If it's running in node, by definition it's not running in a browser. We're you just looking for a way to programmatically download files?

Comment: Yes. And save it to a specific directory.

Comment: Oh, in that case, it can be done with pretty much any language that doesn't run inside a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Node Webkit Apps are not Website, therefore yes, you can do so by using a node module. 
For example, using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html%20fs) (File system) :

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile("myfile.txt", "Yes! with nwjs i can do stuff that i'm not allowed to do in browser!", function(err) {
  if(err)console.log(err)
  else console.log("file saved");
});
```

Maybe you can read the content of your downloaded file and pipe it to where you want :

```
fs.createReadStream(source_file_path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest_file_path))
```

You are not restricted as in the browser.

Comment: But it's a browser right. So basically the contents are same as the websites. And i am not going to write a file, i am going to download a .swf file and just save it locally.